# upgraded xcode to 5.1.1 broke CocosDenshion

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I just upgraded XCode from 5.0.2 to 5.1.1, and now when I try to build my Cocos2d project, I get a whole bunch of errors in CDOpenALSupport.m -- "Values of type OSStatus should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'int' instead.

The thing that's so annoying is I am not even using any of this in my app, so I tried wrapping the entire file in an #if 0; #endif...  And then when I build, I get an error in CCDirectorIOS.h saying

"Redefinition of __ccContentScaleFactor with a different type: 'CGFloat' (aka double) vs float"...

My project is using cocos2d 2.1...  Times like these make me wonder, why did I upgrade XCode!?!

Comment: because xcode continually improves its error reporting to note potential issues - and there are some. As for the CD issues simply do what the message says (cast to int, it's just a few lines that need adapting). The content scale factor has an answer on SO, the problem here is that the variable is declared as float and CGFloat in two different places, both cases should be float.

Comment: but the errors are in code that's NOT mine...  It's in the internal cocos files.  Are you suggesting I should fork the v2 repo since it's not under development anymore and make these changes??

Comment: Exactly. v2 is no longer maintained, and it's normal for code to no longer compile or at least generate warnings whenever Xcode is updated. When you use open-source software, you take ownership to some degree. But you don't necessarily need to fork it, just edit the code in your project. The individual problems are easy to fix, too. Some require a cast, some like the content scale factor just fixing the code to use the same data type for all devices.

Comment: Actually come to think of it, this error might only occur if you build for armv7s (64-bit code). You shouldn't do that with cocos2d v2, it's not 64-bit compatible. Be sure to remove 64-bit OS and armv7s from architectures to ensure all code is compiled as 32-bit code.